# Box-shadow for each table cell not showing in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I need to make box-shadow for each table cell using :before pseudo element. It works perfect in all browsers except firefox.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/UXeBj/4/

html

```
<table class="c-table ">
    <tr class="th">
        <td>column1</td>
        <td>column2</td>
        <td>column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>row3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>row5</td>
        <td>row6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row7</td>
        <td>row8</td>
        <td>row9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row10</td>
        <td>row11</td>
        <td>row12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.c-table tr > td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}
.c-table td:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content:'';
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why you've set shadow to :before pseudoclass?

Comment: jsFiddle code is missing <tr> opening tags too

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/UXeBj/ I needed. Why the question is on hold ?

Comment: Absolute positioned elements can't be in table, as well as table cell can't contain absolute positioned element, your absolute element (in this case it's ::before) takes coordinates for positioning from whole table, and not from its parent - `relative -td` you did you box-shadow via ::pseudo-element, but if you put directly it to `td`, it will work

    .c-table td{
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);    
    
}

http://fiddle.jshell.net/UXeBj/5/

Comment: There is a small visual diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the shadow to appear on a pseudo-element? If you just put the shadow on the td itself you can get the same effect, and it should work cross browser.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/UXeBj/14/

CSS:

```
.c-table td {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

The reason this doesn't work with the pseudo-element is because according to the spec tds, trs, etc. cannot contain absolutely positioned elements. When you try to absolutely position an element within one it might work in some browsers, but I don't believe that the specification defines a behavior for this. So the way browsers handle it can be different. It looks like Webkit based browsers will try and treat td's like a block-level element, where as Gecko just doesn't care and positions it against the first valid containing element.